# Converting an CSV file to a JSON object in Java

Tags: java, json, csv, xls

Is there an open source java library to convert a CSV (or XLS) file to a JSON object?

I tried using [json.cdl](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/json/json-java/csv-to-jsonarray.html), but somehow it does not seem to work for large CSV strings.

I'm trying to find something like http://www.cparker15.com/code/utilities/csv-to-json/, but written in Java.

Comment: possibly not an _exact_ duplicate since it asks specifically for a Java solution.

Comment: OpenCSV is a pretty good library for working with .csv's: https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv - you can use it to get a POJO from a file and then serialize it into another format fairly easily.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Open CSV to map CSV to a Java Bean, and then use JAXB to convert the Java Bean into a JSON object.

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#javabean-integration

http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_your_favorite_class.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is my Java program and hope somebody finds it useful.

Format needs to be like this:

"SYMBOL,DATE,CLOSE_PRICE,OPEN_PRICE,HIGH_PRICE,LOW_PRICE,VOLUME,ADJ_CLOSE

AAIT,2015-02-26 00:00:00.000,-35.152,0,35.152,35.12,679,0

AAL,2015-02-26 00:00:00.000,49.35,50.38,50.38,49.02,7572135,0"

First line is the column headers. No quotation marks anywhere. Separate with commas and not semicolons. You get the deal.

```
/* Summary: Converts a CSV file to a JSON file.*/

//import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class CSVtoJSON extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static File CSVFile;
    private static BufferedReader read;
    private static BufferedWriter write;

    public CSVtoJSON(){
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("comma separated values", "csv");
        JFileChooser choice = new JFileChooser();
        choice.setFileFilter(filter); //limit the files displayed

        int option = choice.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            CSVFile = choice.getSelectedFile();
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Did not select file. Program will exit.", "System Dialog", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);         
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        CSVtoJSON parse = new CSVtoJSON();
        parse.convert();

        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void convert(){
        /*Converts a .csv file to .json. Assumes first line is header with columns*/
        try {
            read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CSVFile));

            String outputName = CSVFile.toString().substring(0, 
                    CSVFile.toString().lastIndexOf(".")) + ".json"; 
            write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(outputName)));

            String line;
            String columns[]; //contains column names
            int num_cols;
            String tokens[];

            int progress = 0; //check progress

            //initialize columns
            line = read.readLine(); 
            columns = line.split(",");
            num_cols = columns.length;


            write.write("["); //begin file as array
            line = read.readLine();


            while(true) {
                tokens = line.split(",");

                if (tokens.length == num_cols){ //if number columns equal to number entries
                    write.write("{");

                    for (int k = 0; k < num_cols; ++k){ //for each column 
                        if (tokens[k].matches("^-?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*$")){ //if a number
                            write.write("\"" + columns[k] + "\": " + tokens[k]);
                            if (k < num_cols - 1) write.write(", ");                                                }
                        else { //if a string
                            write.write("\"" + columns[k] + "\": \"" + tokens[k] + "\"");
                            if (k < num_cols - 1) write.write(", ");
                        }
                    }

                    ++progress; //progress update
                    if (progress % 10000 == 0) System.out.println(progress); //print progress           


                    if((line = read.readLine()) != null){//if not last line
                        write.write("},");
                        write.newLine();
                    }
                    else{
                        write.write("}]");//if last line
                        write.newLine();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //line = read.readLine(); //read next line if wish to continue parsing despite error 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "ERROR: Formatting error line " + (progress + 2)
                     + ". Failed to parse.", 
                            "System Dialog", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);                    
                    System.exit(-1); //error message
                }
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File converted successfully to "     + outputName, 
                    "System Dialog", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

            write.close();
            read.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
    }
```

Requires Swing but comes with a nifty little GUI so those who know absolutely no Java can use it once packaged into an executable .jar. Feel free to improve upon it. Thank you StackOverflow for helping me out all these years.

Answer (score 3):

@Mouscellaneous basically answered this for you so please give him the credit.

Here is what I came up with:

```
package edu.apollogrp.csvtojson;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

public class ConvertCsvToJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        if (args.length > 1) {
            String pathToCsvFile = args[0];
            String javaBeanClassName = "edu.apollogrp.csvtojson.bean." + args[1];
            final File file = new File(pathToCsvFile);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("The file you specified does not exist. path=" + pathToCsvFile);
            }
            Class<?> type = null;
            try {
                type = Class.forName(javaBeanClassName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("The java bean you specified does not exist. className=" + javaBeanClassName);
            }

            HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy strat = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy();
            strat.setType(type);

            CsvToBean csv = new CsvToBean();
            List list = csv.parse(strat, new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
            System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(list));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please specify the path to the csv file.");
        }
    }
}
```

I used maven to include the dependencies, but you could also download them manually and include them in your classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

> I have used excel file in this code.you can use csv.
>   i have wrote this class for particular Excel/csv format which is known to me.

```
import java.io.File;

public class ReadExcel {

    private String inputFile;

    public void setInputFile(String inputFile) {
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    public void read() throws IOException {
        File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
        Workbook w;
        try {
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            // Get the first sheet
            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
            // Loop over first 10 column and lines
            int columns = sheet.getColumns();
            int rows = sheet.getRows();
            ContactList clist = new ContactList();
            ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
            for (int j = 1; j < rows; j++) {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i, j);

                    switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        if (!cell.getContents().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            contact.setSrNo(Integer.parseInt(cell.getContents()));
                        } else {
                            contact.setSrNo(j);
                        }

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        contact.setName(cell.getContents());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        contact.setAddress(cell.getContents());
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        contact.setCity(cell.getContents());
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        contact.setContactNo(cell.getContents());
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        contact.setCategory(cell.getContents());
                        break;
                    }

                }
                contacts.add(contact);

            }
            System.out.println("done");
            clist.setContactList(contacts);
            JSONObject jsonlist = new JSONObject(clist);
            File f = new File("/home/vishal/Downloads/database.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);

            ps.append(jsonlist.toString());

        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ReadExcel test = new ReadExcel();
        test.setInputFile("/home/vishal/Downloads/database.xls");
        test.read();
    }
}
```

i have used jxl.jar for excel reading

Comment: what are the `Workbook`, `Sheet` and `ContactList` classes?

Comment: I don't know the description for this classes when i have imported jxl.jar file i got those classes from this library . If you want i will give details of the afterwords . thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your CSV is simple, then this is easy to write by hand - but CSV can include nasty edge cases with quoting, missing values, etc.

- load the file using `BufferedReader.readLine()`
- use `String.split(",")` to get the value from each line - *NB this approach will only work correctly if your values don't have commas in!*
- write each value to the output using `BufferedWriter`

  - with the necessary JSON braces and quoting

You might want to use a CSV library, then convert to JSON 'by hand'

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8, writing JSON is at hand.

You didn't specify what JSON API you want, so I assume by "JSON object" you mean a string with a serialized JSON object.

What I did in the [CSV Cruncher](https://github.com/OndraZizka/csv-cruncher) project:

1. Load the CSV using [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/). That's a relatively small (~2 MB) library, which actually implements a SQL 2008 database.
2. Query that database using JDBC.
3. Build a JDK JSON object (`javax.json.JsonObject`) and serialize it.

Here's how to do it:

```
static void convertResultToJson(ResultSet resultSet, Path destFile, boolean printAsArray) 
{
            OutputStream outS = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destFile.toFile()));
            Writer outW = new OutputStreamWriter(outS, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            // javax.json way
            JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
            // Columns
            for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex <= metaData.getColumnCount(); colIndex++) {
                addTheRightTypeToJavaxJsonBuilder(resultSet, colIndex, builder);
            }
            JsonObject jsonObject = builder.build();
            JsonWriter writer = Json.createWriter(outW);
            writer.writeObject(jsonObject);
```

The whole implementation is [here](https://github.com/OndraZizka/csv-cruncher/blob/master/src/main/java/cz/dynawest/csvcruncher/FilesUtils.java#L78). (Originally I wrote my own CSV parsing and JSON writing, but figured out both are complicated enough to reach for a tested off-the-shelf library.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class I generated to return JSONArray, not just to print to a file.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class CsvToJson {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UtilsFormat.class);
private static CsvToJson instance;


public static JSONArray convert(File input) throws Exception {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.builder().setUseHeader(true).build();
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

    // Read data from CSV file
    List<? extends Object> readAll = csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class).with(csvSchema).readValues(input).readAll();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    JSONArray jsonObject = (JSONArray) parser.parse(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(readAll));
    System.out.print(jsonObject.toString());

    return new JSONArray();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you can do something like this. No Libraries or complicated logic required.

Firstly, create a POJO representing your new JSON object. In my example it's called 'YourJSONObject' and has a constructor taking two strings.

What the code does is initially reads the file, then creates a stream of String based lines. ( a line is equivalent to a line in your CSV file).

We then pass the line in to the map function which splits it on a comma and then creates the YourJSONObject.

All of these objects are then collected to a list which we pass in to the JSONArray constructor.

You now have an Array of JSONObjects. You can then call toString() on this object if you want to see the text representation of this.

```
        JSONArray objects = new JSONArray(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("src/main/resources/your_csv_file.csv"))
            .stream()
            .map(s -> new YourJSONObject(s.split(",")[0], s.split(",")[1]))
            .collect(toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I thought I'd share my own solution. It assumes quotations are used around an in-value comma. It also removes all quotations afterwards.

This method accepts a String in CSV format. So it assumes you've already read the CSV file to a string. Make sure you didn't remove the NextLine characters ('\n') while reading.

This method in no way perfect, but it might be the quick one-method solution in pure java you are looking for.

```
public String CSVtoJSON(String output) {

    String[] lines = output.split("\n");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append('[');
    String[] headers = new String[0];

    //CSV TO JSON
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        String[] values = lines[i].replaceAll("\"", "").split("۞");

        if (i == 0) //INDEX LIST
        {
            headers = values;
        } else {
            builder.append('{');
            for (int j = 0; j < values.length && j < headers.length; j++) {

                String jsonvalue = "\"" + headers[j] + "\":\"" + values[j] + "\"";
                if (j != values.length - 1) { //if not last value of values...
                    jsonvalue += ',';
                }
                builder.append(jsonvalue);
            }
            builder.append('}');
            if (i != lines.length - 1) {
                builder.append(',');
            }
        }
    }
    builder.append(']');
    output = builder.toString();

    return output;
}
```