# Converting csv row to JSON object in Java

Tags: java, json, csv, jackson

I've a csv file something similar to this

```
"name.firstName","name.givenName","name.DisplayName","phone.type","phone.value"
"john","maverick","John Maverick","mobile","123-123-123"
"jim","lasher","Jim Lasher","mobile","123-123-123"
```

I want to convert the 2nd and 3rd row into JSON objects.Using the first row as Header. So the result will be

```
[
{  
"name": {
    "firstName": "john",
    "givenName": "maverick",
    "DisplayName": "John Maverick"
},
"phone": {
    "type": "mobile",
    "value": "123-123-123"
}
},
{
"name": {
    "firstName": "john",
    "givenName": "maverick",
    "DisplayName": "John Maverick"
},
"phone": {
    "type": "mobile",
    "value": "123-123-123"
}
]
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Create the Array and Map objects that represent the structure, then serialize them into JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Java library that may help you. http://www.jonathanhfisher.co.uk/playpen/csv2json/index.htm

Here is a JavaScript library that may or may not be useful to you. http://www.cparker15.com/code/utilities/csv-to-json/

And finally, here is a past answer that may be useful. I like the OpenCSV solution. However, instead of JAXB, you could use Jackson. [Converting an CSV file to a JSON object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524191/converting-an-csv-file-to-a-json-object-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in this third solution, the example code which is used is

ColumnPositionMappingStrategy strat = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
strat.setType(YourOrderBean.class);
String[] columns = new String[] {"name", "orderNumber", "id"}; // the fields to bind do in your JavaBean
strat.setColumnMapping(columns);

CsvToBean csv = new CsvToBean();
List list = csv.parse(strat, yourReader);

what exactly is yourReader here, and how do I input values to bind with bean? Thanks

Comment: I believe the yourReader is the inputFileReader.

Comment: yeah got it thanks, also is there any documentation for using Jackson to covert javaBean to JSON? Thanks again.

Comment: This looks like a nice tutorial, but I haven't had a chance to go through it yet. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: If my answer was helpful, can you up vote it and/or select it as the correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @robbr. I'm stuck in another problem here, when I map csv to JavaBean, for the attributes of my bean object not present in the csv, they are being assigned to null. I want to map only the values present in csvHeader to the attributes of my bean object. Can you tell me a way to do this? I've created a seperate question for this over here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596438/csv-to-bean-excluding-the-values-not-included-in-csv-header-java