# How to remove element from javax.json.JsonArray in java?

Tags: java, json, collections

In my requirement I am reading JsonArray (javax.json.JsonArray) from the local file like below:

```
JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new FileReader(path));
JsonArray regAttribArr = reader.readObject().getJsonObject("Entries")
                .getJsonArray("Attributes");
reader.close();
```

After that while removing the element from that array like below,

```
JsonValue tempjv = regAttribArr.get(0);
regAttribArr.remove(tempjv);
```

it is throwing **UnsupportedOperationException** as JsonArray class is unmodifiable list.

Is there any alternate way to delete the element from this javax.json.JsonArray object ?

Comment: The `javax.json` JSON types are immutable. You'll have to build copies yourself ("copies" that don't include what you want to remove).

Comment: In my requirement I am having the list of json objects coming from request payload,each of which are one by one compared with the list of json objects read from the file. Whenever the match found for any of the json object that object needs to be remove from the JsonArray read from the file.As per the comment every time it needs to traverse as well as need to create new jsonarray object.So it will be much time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you may be better off copying the list item-by-item and skipping over the one you don't want.

An unmodifiable list is just going to be unmodifiable

Comment: Or create a new instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47075432