# Remove specific values in a JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I'm have a RecyclerView with selectable items in it. If an item is selected, I put a new field in its JSONObject("selected": true). Below is my JSONArray from logcat called (filteredList).

This is my filteredList JSON :

```
[{
"nr": 1,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "MORE SALT",
"selected": true
}, {
"nr": 2,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "MORE SWEET"
}, {
"nr": 3,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "MORE PEPPER"
}, {
"nr": 4,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "MORE CHILLI",
"selected": true
}, {
"nr": 5,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "COLD"
}, {
"nr": 6,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "HOT"
}, {
"nr": 7,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "SMALL"
}, {
"nr": 8,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "LARGE"
}, {
"nr": 9,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "MEDIUM COOKED"
}, {
"nr": 10,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "WELL DONE"
}]
```

I'd like to make my filteredList JSON look like this (essentially removing all `selected` fields):

```
[{
"nr": 1,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "MORE SALT"
}, {
"nr": 2,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "MORE SWEET"
}, {
"nr": 3,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "MORE PEPPER"
}, {
"nr": 4,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "MORE CHILLI"
}, {
"nr": 5,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "COLD"
}, {
"nr": 6,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "HOT"
}, {
"nr": 7,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "SMALL"
}, {
"nr": 8,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "LARGE"
}, {
"nr": 9,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "MEDIUM COOKED"
}, {
"nr": 10,
"grpnr": 0,
"bezeich": "WELL DONE"
}]
```

As we see, some object have the field `"selected"`. I want to know how to delete only this field. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603033/removing-json-elements-with-jackson) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820551/how-do-i-remove-a-specific-element-from-a-jsonarray) but its not working in my case. Any answer will help, thank in advance!

It doesn't work because my CheckBox only removes the last checked item.

here's my code snippet:

```
JSONObject check = new JSONObject();
    try {
        check = orderList.getJSONObject(intCurrArticleNr);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(check.has("spesial-request")) {
        try {
            String arrayRemarkString = check.getString("spesial-request");

            if (remarkObj.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(arrayRemarkString)) {
                currRemark = new JSONArray(check.getString("spesial-request"));
                edt_reqList.setText(currRemark.toString().trim());

                System.out.println(currRemark);
            }
            else {
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {

// here i have a probelem //
        remarkObj = new JSONArray();
//            objectReqList.remove("selected");

        int len = filteredReqList.length();
        JSONArray teslist = new JSONArray();
        if (filteredReqList == null) {
            for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
                filteredReqList.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? Does it throw an exception? Does it just not remove the fields? Please elaborate. Also show us the expected json vs the json u get. Lastly some code would be nice so we can see what you are doing wrong

Comment: Sorry i'll edit

Comment: while filling your Recycler view check if `selected` exists then don't put it in recycler view . its one approach other may also be there.

Comment: @jackjay i'll try that , but i'm still curious with this case

Comment: @MarioMargoPradipta You can just iterate and remove, check my answer below - I tested with your JSON, it gives me the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate and remove, try with below - It works fine.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
        "sample.json"));

JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Before --" + jsonArray.get(i).toString());
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i);
    jsonObject.remove("selected");
    System.out.println("After --" + jsonArray.get(i).toString());
}
System.out.println("Final Output --" + jsonArray.toString());
```

Output -

```
Before --{"selected":true,"nr":1,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"MORE SALT"}
After --{"nr":1,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"MORE SALT"} 
Before --{"nr":2,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"MORE SWEET"} 
After --{"nr":2,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"MORE SWEET"} 
Before --{"nr":3,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"MORE PEPPER"} 
After --{"nr":3,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"MORE PEPPER"} 
Before --{"selected":true,"nr":4,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"MORE CHILLI"} 
After --{"nr":4,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"MORE CHILLI"} 
Before --{"nr":5,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"COLD"} 
After --{"nr":5,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"COLD"} 
Before --{"nr":6,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"HOT"} 
After --{"nr":6,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"HOT"} 
Before --{"nr":7,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"SMALL"} 
After --{"nr":7,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"SMALL"} 
Before --{"nr":8,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"LARGE"} 
After --{"nr":8,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"LARGE"} 
Before --{"nr":9,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"MEDIUM COOKED"} 
After --{"nr":9,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"MEDIUM COOKED"} 
Before --{"nr":10,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"WELL DONE"} 
After --{"nr":10,"grpnr":0,"bezeich":"WELL DONE"} 
Final Output -- [{
    "nr": 1,
    "grpnr": 0,
    "bezeich": "MORE SALT"
}, {
    "nr": 2,
    "grpnr": 0,
    "bezeich": "MORE SWEET"
}, {
    "nr": 3,
    "grpnr": 0,
    "bezeich": "MORE PEPPER"
}, {
    "nr": 4,
    "grpnr": 0,
    "bezeich": "MORE CHILLI"
}, {
    "nr": 5,
    "grpnr": 0,
    "bezeich": "COLD"
}, {
    "nr": 6,
    "grpnr": 0,
    "bezeich": "HOT"
}, {
    "nr": 7,
    "grpnr": 0,
    "bezeich": "SMALL"
}, {
    "nr": 8,
    "grpnr": 0,
    "bezeich": "LARGE"
}, {
    "nr": 9,
    "grpnr": 0,
    "bezeich": "MEDIUM COOKED"
}, {
    "nr": 10,
    "grpnr": 0,
    "bezeich": "WELL DONE"
}]
```

Comment: Good !! Thanks @MarioMargoPradipta

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
for (int i = 0; i < filteredReqList.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject item = filteredReqList.getJSONObject(i);
    item.remove("selected");
}
```