# Remove one JSON data from a file of JSON's

Tags: java, json, jackson

my JSON is :

```
{
  "errorMessages" : [ {
    "key" : "QUIESCE_FAILURE",
    "code" : "12345",
    "description" : "User already exists aaa",
    "reason" : "Username {user} is already added aaa",
    "resolution" : "Please provide a different username aaa",
    "more_information" : "more info aaa",
    "type" : "error aaa"
  }, {
    "key" : "DUPLICATE_USERS",
    "code" : "3114587",
    "description" : "Failed to quiesce database(s)",
    "reason" : "Database {database} on host {host} is not accessible",
    "resolution" : "Please check that the database is accessible",
    "more_information" : "kkkk",
    "type" : "error"
  } ]
}
```

i want to delete json with code 3114587 using jackson.

may i get any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code.

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603033/removing-json-elements-with-jackson

Comment: de-serialise the data to a list, do an operation on it to remove the desired list item just like in any other list variable, then re-serialise the changed list back to JSON. JSON is a text-based transmission/storage format, you shouldn't attempt to manipulate it directly.

Comment: Have a look at:stackoverflow.com/questions/15603033/… – Prashant Pimpale  
I want to delete one complete JSON element not any particular field in json .

after this output should be


{
  "errorMessages" : [ {
    "key" : "QUIESCE_FAILURE",
    "code" : "12345",
    "description" : "User already exists aaa",
    "reason" : "Username {user} is already added aaa",
    "resolution" : "Please provide a different username aaa",
    "more_information" : "more info aaa",
    "type" : "error aaa"
  } ]
}

Comment: @yashaswinijayshankar the principle is still the same. The "element" you refer to is just an object with an array. It's still one particular index / field within that array. You might need a particular different method since it's not a named property, but perhaps you can research what that method is called (sorry I only know JSON and a tiny bit of Java, nothing specific to the Jackson library)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have your JSON contents as a `File` object.
If you have it as an `URL`, `InputStream`, `Reader` or `String`,
then just modify the code below by taking another `readValue` method.

With the classes from packages [`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/package-summary.html)
and [`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/package-summary.html)
you can achieve your goal in a straight-forward way.
Read the JSON input, find and remove the array element, and write the JSON output:

```
File file = ...;
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);  // for pretty print
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readValue(file, JsonNode.class);
ArrayNode errorMessages = (ArrayNode) jsonNode.get("errorMessages");
for (int i = 0; i < errorMessages.size(); i++) {
    ObjectNode errorMessage = (ObjectNode) errorMessages.get(i);
    String code = errorMessage.get("code").asText();
    if (code.equals("3114587")) {
        errorMessages.remove(i);  // remove the element
    }
}
objectMapper.writeValue(System.out, jsonNode);
```

Answer (score -1):

`delete json[key];`

Store your Json object in a variable name json. Find the key that you want to delete and it should work.

Comment: can you demonstrate that in context? It doesn't look like Java code to me.