# Read CSV value inside JSON file

Tags: java, oracle, csv, clob, json-simple

I have a problem where I have to read a JSON File and extract a large CSV value from one of the attributes, process it ( get some overall information like CSV number of rows , columns... ) and then save it to the database.

For this I am using json-simple to parse the json file and extract the csv value from its attribute.
I am getting some heap problems so there must be a problem while getting the whole csv value to java.lang.String.

I'd like to know the best way to do this, since I am afraid that using jackson or other stream based approach lib won't help at all.

Best regards,
Ĩvan Frias

Comment: "I am getting some heap problems" can you exactly point out what problems?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580474/converting-csv-row-to-json-object-in-java might be duplicate question please refer this