# For jmeter post request, how can I generate input json from csv file?

Tags: json, rest, csv, post, jmeter

I am trying to make a post rest call to my service. My sample input json file is,

{
  "$id": "1",
  "description": "sfdasd"
}

I have one csv file which contain a bunch of id and description, So is there a option where I can convert csv file to json objects and pass them to post call?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming your CSV file is called `test.csv`, located in JMeter's "bin" folder and  looks like:

[image: CSV Example Structure]

1. Add [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your Test Plan and configure it as follows:

   [image]
2. You can inline the defined [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) directly into your request body like:

   ```
   {
     "$id": "${id}",
     "description": "${description}"
   }
   ```

   [image: JMeter HTTP Request]
3. So when you run the test the variables placeholders will automatically be substituted with the values from the CSV file in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

   [image]

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) article for more information on JMeter tests parameterization using CSV files.

Comment: is there a way, to use each line in a file as json request body data directly. (note: each line is a single json object with multiple key values and i dont want to declare each of the  variables manually)

Answer (score 1):

Json is just text. Send as is with the variable id taken from csv:

```
 { "${id}": "1", "description": "sfdasd" }
```

Comment: Where should this be added ?

Comment: Inside Body data

Comment: The right syntax would be : { "id":${id},"description":${description}" }, this syntax will create the json as you have shown in your comment. That is not the syntax rather the output imo. Also, there won't be a dollar sign before id.

Answer (score 0):

CSV data can be converted to JSON via a POJO using Jackson. If a POJO is not already defined or required, you can always use the Java Collection classes to store parsed data and later convert it to JSON. http://www.novixys.com/blog/convert-csv-json-java/ is a good reference on how to convert csv to java.
You can check the following links too.
1. [directly convert CSV file to JSON file using the Jackson library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766266/directly-convert-csv-file-to-json-file-using-the-jackson-library)
2. [Converting an CSV file to a JSON object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524191/converting-an-csv-file-to-a-json-object-in-java)